# android handler run() seem to be called twice i s Samsung Galaxy

Tags: android, handler

```
    class WaitingThread extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            if (FLAG_GETMESSAGE) {
                break;
            }
        }

        handle.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), mGameView.getCurrentPlayer().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mGameView.setCell(message_cell, mGameView.getCurrentPlayer());
                FLAG_GETMESSAGE = false;
                handle.removeCallbacks(this);
                Exception e = new Exception();
                e.printStackTrace();
                finishTurn();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

It is simple tic tac toe game with bluetooth multiplayer. it was made from Android sample tictactoe lib(https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/TicTacToeLib) and BluetoothChat(Android SDK Sample).

In Original TicTacToeLib, player end his choice and call finishTurn() method. then Random cell has selected, and call finishTurn(). and it's loop.

So as I wanted to implement bluetooth multiplayer, I deleted random cell selection code and start Thread(infinite loop with check boolean FLAG_GETMESSAGE), and bluetooth callback(called when get message from bluetooth) change FLAG_GETMESSAGE to true.

I tested on two device, SM-N910S(Samsung galaxy note 4), LG-KU5400(LG Prada 3.0)... in LG-KU5400, it works perfectly fine. but in SM-N910S, when LG-KU5400 select first, handler's run() called twice(On SM-N910S), so both device think that it's other's turn now...

printStackTrace()'s result is...

```
04-05 07:33:42.973    8538-8538/com.example.android.tictactoe W/System.err﹕ at com.example.android.tictactoe.GameActivity$**WaitingThread$1.run(GameActivity.java:617)**
**04-05 07:33:42.973**    8538-8538/com.example.android.tictactoe W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
04-05 07:33:42.973    8538-8538/com.example.android.tictactoe W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
04-05 07:33:42.973    8538-8538/com.example.android.tictactoe W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
04-05 07:33:42.973    8538-8538/com.example.android.tictactoe W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5972)
04-05 07:33:42.973    8538-8538/com.example.android.tictactoe W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
04-05 07:33:42.973    8538-8538/com.example.android.tictactoe W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
04-05 07:33:42.973    8538-8538/com.example.android.tictactoe W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
04-05 07:33:42.973    8538-8538/com.example.android.tictactoe W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
04-05 07:33:42.978    8538-8538/com.example.android.tictactoe W/System.err﹕ java.lang.Exception
04-05 07:33:42.978    8538-8538/com.example.android.tictactoe W/System.err﹕ at com.example.android.tictactoe.GameActivity$**WaitingThread$1.run(GameActivity.java:617)**
**04-05 07:33:42.978**    8538-8538/com.example.android.tictactoe W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
04-05 07:33:42.978    8538-8538/com.example.android.tictactoe W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
04-05 07:33:42.978    8538-8538/com.example.android.tictactoe W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
04-05 07:33:42.978    8538-8538/com.example.android.tictactoe W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5972)
04-05 07:33:42.978    8538-8538/com.example.android.tictactoe W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
04-05 07:33:42.978    8538-8538/com.example.android.tictactoe W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
04-05 07:33:42.978    8538-8538/com.example.android.tictactoe W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
04-05 07:33:42.978    8538-8538/com.example.android.tictactoe W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

Why these happened and how can I solve it?

I read some solution when handler's run() called twice, so add handle.removeCallbacks(this) but it dosen't work.

and works wrong on JUST SM-N910S is also strange...

P.S. when I use Android Studio's breakpoint debug(on SM-N910S), sometime it works correctly(SOMETIMES).. is it multi thread's share resource problem? but why it happened on LG-KU5400?